# How UIViewControllers created - by alloc/init vs. performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

My iOS 8 project uses a Storyboard, wherein I have a `UINavigationController`, with a root `UIViewController`; let's call this **`A`**. I also have another `UIViewController`, connected via a Segue to this root controller; let's call this **`B`**. Pretty standard configuration.

Now, **`A`** is a subclassed `UITableViewController`, and in the table I have a list of URLs. The app user taps a table cell, the URL is extracted and passed to **`B`**. **`B`** is a subclassed `UIViewController` that contains a `WKWebView`.

Now, because **`B`** is on the `UINavigationController`'s stack, users can tap the Back button while in **`B`**, returning to the table with the URLs (**`A`**). The user can then tap another cell, to load another URL.

Because I need to pass some data (the URL) to **`B`**, I'm invoking it with `performSegueWithIdentifier`, and in the corresponding `prepareForSegue`, I assign the URL to a property in **`B`**.

This all works fine. My questions reflect my still-nOOb status with respect to iOS and Objective-C.

The first question, when **`B`** is created via the `performSegueWithIdentifier` / `prepareForSegue` combo, when the user taps the Back button, is this controller deallocated by the OS? In other words, there's no longer an instance of this subclassed `UIViewController` floating around?

If it is, then presumably it's safe to have a new instance of it created if the user taps a table cell to view another URL. In other words, repeating the call to `performSegueWithIdentifier`, assigning the newly chosen URL in **`B`**'s property, etc. Is it safe?

Or, if it's not deallocated automatically, then does repeating the call to `performSegueWithIdentifier`, etc. just keep creating more and more instances of **`B`**?

And, in either case, does it make sense to, when **`B`** is first created, capture a reference to it, and keep re-using it? In other words, before calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`, check if a reference to **`B`** already exists, and if it does, do a `pushViewController` with that reference to **`B`**?

So the basic question boils down to this: In a situation where a `UIViewController` needs to be made visible many times - through a user action - is an instance being newly created every time it's needed? If it is, then does this also imply that every instance is also being deallocated internally when it's no longer needed? And therefore I don't need to worry about the internals?

Or, if I keep using `performSegueWithIdentifier` every time, am I just creating a pile of new instances of the controller, and thus being wasteful and inefficient, when I could just capture a reference to the first new instance and keep re-using it?

I've tried to step through this process in the debugger and keep track of references, but I'm unsure whether I'm seeing what I should be seeing, and so I'm asking more knowledgeable developers.

Thank you for reading through this long question, and for your time in answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you push view and pop view and if you are not retaining that view controller anywhere else then it will be released completely and it doesn't really matter how many time you call performSegueWithIdentifier to create this view if you are not retaining it or manage it reference well enough.
However, in this case, I would create your 'B' view controller once using

```
 self.bController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BController"];
```

And then you call pushViewController using self.bController, function would be looking something like this..

```
- (void)presentURL:(NSString*)url
{
    if ( self.bController == nil ) {
        self.bController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BController"];
    }

    [self.bController setURL:url];

    [viewController.navigationController pushViewController:self.bController animated:YES];
}
```

And refresh the WKWebView with below code when it sets the URL

```
-(void)setUrlString:(NSString *)urlString {
    // set url string
    _urlString = urlString;

    // clear
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];

    // load url with string
    if( _urlString != nil ) {
        // get address for hosting view
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlString];
        NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }
}
```

it will make bit simpler than prepareForSegue, however, again, repeating the call to performSegueWithIdentifier, assigning the newly chosen URL in B's property, etc. It is totally safe as long as you don't retaining anywhere else.. but performance wise it might be bit expensive than keeping one instance of B viewController and showing it multiple time because it has to read and initiate the view controller and the WKWebView instance so arguably it is bit expansive..

Comment: Great answer - thank you. So you do confirm that as long as no explicit retaining of references to the controller, it is being released. That's what I really was unsure about. And the sample code you give reflects a lot of what I already have in place, so good confirmation there as well. Thanks a lot!

You're the only one who's answered my questions, and assuming I don't hear anything else or vastly different, I will mark this as answered by you. Thanks!